# Converting a string currency to a numeric value in Visual studio. How do I do that?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How do I convert a string currency (like $100, $1111 etc.) into a numerical value so that I can do math operations?

I have tried:

```
Dim result as Decimal
result = val(textbox1.text) + val(textbox2.text)
label1.text = result
```

also

```
Dim result as Decimal
result = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) + Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.text)
label1.text = result
```

but I have no luck.
I figured that when the dollar sign is not there, the calculation works smoothly with val(), but I need to display the dollar sign so user will know that it is a currency.
Are there anyway to ignore the dollar sign? 
Thank you.

Comment: call decimal.parse with a currency NumberStyles parameter. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Also, you'll probably get better answers if you add the "vb.net" or "vba" tag, whichever is more appropriate.

Comment: @BurnsBA Thank you, I have edited my tags now. And for the Decimal.Parse, I tried Decimal.Parse(textbox1.text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency) but it's giving me an "Input string was not in a correct format" error.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Substring method to eliminate the dollar sign:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2

So for your use it would look something like:

```
myDollarAmount = "$100"
myDollarAmountNoSign = myDollarAmount.Substring(1)
```

If you then took "myDollarAmountNoSign" and printed, you would get "100".

Once you take the substring, the string can then be cast to an int, or whatever other number type is your preference.

The "1" in the Substring() method is the index we start at to take the substring. Each character in the string has an index, for example with the string "string", the index values would be:

0: "s", 1: "t", 2: "r", 3: "i", 4: "n", 5: "g"

Say we took string.Substring(2), we would get "ring"

Comment: I would suggest using [Trim(Char\[\])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead, in case the currency symbol is not present or the user put it at the end.

Comment: [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) => [NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) & Co. => [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netframework-4.7.2)